# Arrays & Curves & Scaling？

Tags: modifiers

Too much gap in spine after scaling curves, how should I modify to normal state?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to reduce both the size and the gap, first set the curve vertex radius back to 1 and use the *Object Offset* of the *Array*, with an empty as *Object*, and scale down the empty:

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... but doesn't that just change the size of the objects along the curve? It's not changing the distance between them, or is it?

Comment: @Gordon Brinkmann oh ok I may have misinterpreted his question, I've edited

Comment: I guess since it's a spine, the increasing size is intentional...

Comment: Thank you, this is what I want... just a little difficult to adjust